# Should I avoid aggregates (DDD) in a system without an event store?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I'm looking into the possibility of adopting the concept of (root) aggregates from domain-driven design in a system without an event store. However, the more I discover about the two, the more it feels like the one cannot exist without the other.

I haven't finished reading the blue book yet, but my understanding of a root aggregate so far is that it's a "tree" of aggregates that needs to be consistent within that root aggregate. An aggregate can only be modified through the root aggregate it belongs to. Finally, a root can basically be defined by "does it make sense to have this aggregate independent and can it exist by itself in this domain?".

Imagine a green-field project where it doesn't make sense to engineer event sourcing yet, but might benefit from it in the future. The absence of an event store would eliminate the possibility to keep track of all the domain events shaping a root aggregate at a specific point in time. The commands would have to mutate the root aggregate. In addition, the read side would be limited to react on "root aggregate {id} has updated" as there's no event replayability.

Is there any reasonable way for the concept of (root) aggregates to exist without an event store, or should one stick to the "traditional" entity modeling until it makes sense to invest in event sourcing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you are confusing things. There's no such thing as root aggregate or a tree of aggregates.

The main purpose of the aggregate tactical pattern in DDD to exist is to define the consistency boundary, which technically translates to the transactional boundary. Everything inside one aggregate can change when you handle a single command, but no more.

An aggregate can consist of several entity types. However, only one entity type serves as the *aggregate root*. The aggregate root id is the identity for the whole aggregate. Other entities inside the aggregate will have their ids (otherwise these aren't entities but value objects) but those entities cannot be amended or referred directly from outside of the aggregate and all operations on all entities inside one aggregate go vis the aggregate root.

The most typical example of an aggregate is the `Order`, where `Order` itself (or `OrderHead` if you like) is the root and `OrderLine` is the entity. You can have multiple order lines for one order but all operations on any line go via the root.

There's no direct and explicit connection between the aggregate pattern and event-sourcing. Event-sourcing is the implementation details. Eric Evans book doesn't even mention event-sourcing as such and it has quite a few examples of aggregates.

Event-sourcing is the way to persist data. In fact, event-sourcing is completely unrelated to DDD, although Greg Young originally proposed using event-sourcing as the way to persist aggregates by storing domain events.

When you have a pure domain model, it doesn't really matter from the domain model side what persistence mechanism you use. Many event-sourced systems have no concept of aggregate at all. For example, The New York Times [has built](https://www.confluent.io/blog/publishing-apache-kafka-new-york-times/) an event-sourced content management system without any DDD tactical pattern in mind. From the other side, the majority of systems that use tactical DDD patterns do not use event-sourcing and use just state-based persistence.

Comment: I would just like to add to @Alexey's excellent answer and mention that when using event sourcing your aggregate design is slightly different from the *traditional* approach in that you are going to be emitting events as output to your commands and storing those for replay.  A more *traditional* approach would have to store and re-hydrate the state of the aggregate in some other way.  I am working on an existing network packet capture system currently where trading/clearing platform messages are decoded and analysed and they follow event sourcing concepts with no DDD in sight :)

Comment: Thank you, clear and helpful answer! You're correct, I was confusing the aggregate as a thing rather than a tactic. I thought an aggregate is an alternative to an entity. I also thought that I broke the aggregate principles when I persist the data in a normalized way. Coupled with @Eben's comment, I realized I might already be using the aggregate tactics. I do re-hydrate the normalized data into a "root entity" with related entities that are programmatically only modified through that "root entity" (= root aggregate?). These pointers should help me, thanks again! :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on Event Sourcing. It's not a must have. Thanks @Alexey